# GetUserName under Win64

Tags: c, winapi, 64-bit

I am trying to compile a C program using the Intel icl compiler under MINGW/64. The program uses the following code:

```
#include <Userenv.h>
HANDLE process;
HANLDE token;
GetUserProfileDirectory(process, TOKEN_QUERY, &ptoken)
```

I am using the following compile command:

```
$ icl -g -DMINGW32 -DTESTMAIN user.c -o user -UserEnv.Lib
```

and I am linking against the UserEnv.Lib from the Microsoft SDK.

Intel(R) C++ Intel(R) 64 Compiler XE for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 9.00.21022.08
    -out:user.exe
    user.obj

```
user.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetUserProfileDirectoryA referenced in function main
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

**SOLUTION:**
The solution is to use

/link /c/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ SDKs/Windows/v6.0A/Lib/x64/UserEnv.Lib  /c/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ SDKs/Windows/v6.0A/Lib/x64/A

---

I copied the file UserEnv.lib from the Microsoft SDK (x64, 6.0) into the current working directory and compiled the program with

$ icl test.c -DMINGW32 ./UserEnv.Lib

LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetUserNameA referenced in function main test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_OpenProcessToken referenced in function main test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol –

and I am still getting the unresolved symbols.

Olaf

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `userenv.lib` to your input libraries for the linker to see [GetUserProfileDirectory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762280%28VS.85%29.aspx).

**EDIT:** It's been a while since I've touched an Intel compiler, but IIRC you're supposed to use `/link` to introduce linker options:

```
$ icl test.c -DMINGW32 /link ./UserEnv.Lib
```

Comment: I copied the file UserEnv.lib from the Microsoft SDK (x64, 6.0) into the current working directory and compiled the program with

Comment: I copied the file UserEnv.lib from the Microsoft SDK (x64, 6.0) into the current working directory and compiled the program with $ icl test.c  -DMINGW32  UserEnv.Lib

icl: NOTE: The evaluation period for this product ends on 10-dec-2010 UTC.
test.c
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetUserNameA referenced in function main
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_OpenProcessToken referenced in function main
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Comment: I copied the file UserEnv.lib from the Microsoft SDK (x64, 6.0) into the current working directory and compiled the program with $ icl test.c -DMINGW32 UserEnv.Lib icl: NOTE: The evaluation period for this product ends on 10-dec-2010 UTC. test.c test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetUserNameA referenced in function main test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_OpenProcessToken referenced in function main test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Comment: Please aplogize for posting the message three times.

Comment: @Olaf, you should update your original question with these error messages instead of trying to fit them into comments.

Comment: @Frederic: Ok, I did it. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Olaf, I took the liberty to edit your question and to update my answer accordingly. Remember, you should update your original question rather than adding information in comments or in your own answers :)